# 404 after Artifactory Pro upgrade from 6.x to 7.x

Tags: artifactory

After upgrading from 6.16 to the freshest (7.2.1) I get 404 when trying to access the UI in browser.

In `derby.log` I see the following:

```
Tue Mar 24 06:26:39 UTC 2020 Thread[localhost-startStop-2,5,main] (XID = 67000717), (SESSIONID = 3), (DATABASE = /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/derby), (DRDAID = null), Cleanup action starting
Tue Mar 24 06:26:39 UTC 2020 Thread[localhost-startStop-2,5,main] (XID = 67000717), (SESSIONID = 3), (DATABASE = /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/derby), (DRDAID = null), Failed Statement is: INSERT INTO access_configs (config_name, modified, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?) with 3 parameters begin parameter #1: shared.security.joinKey :end parameter begin parameter #2: 1585031199475 :end parameter begin parameter #3: BLOB:Length=93 :end parameter
ERROR 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'ACCESS_CONFIGS_PK' defined on 'ACCESS_CONFIGS'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error should not prevent Artifactory from starting. `404` after migration to Artifactory 7 usually means you didn't change your reverse proxy config from `8081` (on which Artifactory ran on version 6) to `8082` (the new port for Artifactory in version 7).

While the embedded Tomcat redirects directly, if you use a reverse proxy, such as Nginx, you have to update the redirection rules manually, as described [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+NGINX).

Comment: Thanks, the error in the logs was misleading. The problem was in NGINX configuration which should have been rewritten after upgrade to 7.x.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but tomcat didn't start on 8082, it is still running on 8081 after upgrading from 6.16 to 7.4. So even after fixing nginx it still returns 404. No logs except for the successful migration log and no files in the /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat folder. What could be the problem, how can I make tomcat start on 8082 and/or serve the correct files?